# I cannot write to /dev/sda6

Tags: dual-boot, ntfs, read-only, devices

I have Ubuntu 17.04 on my Asus laptop.

After login I cannot write anything to `/dev/sda6`

It tells me that the disk is in read-only mode:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is that an NTFS partition?

Comment: What is the result of `ls -ld .` when you are in this directory?

Comment: @Zanna yes it's NTFS ...

Comment: @Romeo Ninov
drwxrwxrwx 1 ahmed ahmed 8192 Jun 27 01:02 .

Comment: you cant access that partition because windows already mounted it, reset your laptop properly, since windows 8+, windows just suspends the disks when you click "shutdown" thats how they improved the rapid launch when turning on the computers, so go to windows and restart the computer dont shutdown

Comment: Note : I have windows 10 along side ubuntu 17.04

Comment: @RenatoA. .. okay I'll will try that now ...

Comment: :D glad , please edit the title and put SOLVED

Comment: No, don't put SOLVED into the title. We don't do that around here. Instead, @RenatoA., please post your comment as an answer, and Ahmed, please tick the green mark next to it, to mark your question as answered.

Comment: hey @Ahmed you want me to put an answer? since you alreafy fixed it I dont think is crucial

Comment: @AhmedDawlatAl-Ahmed what theme and icon pack of dolphin are you using ? I like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, its probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

**In Windows...**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C: